# Trying to hitTestObject in javascript with no success

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code and I have done something like this before and I got it to work, I just want the code below to be kind of similar but in working form. I know it can be done, there is always a way.

```
var playerX = document.getElementById("character").style.left;
var playerY = document.getElementById("character").style.top;
var playerW = document.getElementById("character").style.width;
var playerH = document.getElementById("character").style.height;
        
var enemy100X = document.getElementById("enemy100").style.left;
var enemy100Y = document.getElementById("enemy100").style.top;
var enemy100W = document.getElementById("enemy100").style.width;
var enemy100H = document.getElementById("enemy100").style.height;
        
        
if (enemy100X > playerX - 15 &&
    enemy100X < playerX + 15 && 
    enemy100Y > playerY - 10 &&
    enemy100Y < playerY + 10) {
    enemyDetection = 1;
}
```

Is there a way to get this to work? And also to note that both objects basically have the same Y position off by 3 VH. And also both Objects rotate.

I have tried this method, even swapping playerX with enemy100X and it dont work.

```
if (playerX + playerW >= enemy100X &&
    playerX <= enemy100X + enemy100W &&
    playerY + playerH >= enemy100Y &&
    playerY <= enemy100Y + enemy100H) {
    enemyDetection = 1;
}
```

And these are the images:

[image: ENEMY]
[image: PLAYER]

Answer (score 0):

## Mapping position and size to HTML elements:

You are using the element's style to deal with the size and position but it should be the other way around. Having a state that you use to derive the style would be more appropriate. So that your logics isn't strictly coupled with the presentation. For example you could have plain numbers for your coords that would be passed to the presentation layers as pixels.

Additionally the `.style` property of an element will only return the element inline style properties and it would need to be initialized upfront. For example if you set `top` `left` `width` `height` via a css rule it won't be visible to the `.style` property.

### getBoundingClientRect - A better approach:

If you need to know the actual size and position you should rely on `getBoundingClientRect`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns a DOMRect object
> providing information about the size of an element and its position
> relative to the viewport.

Here's a demo showing the two approaches and their result. I also stripped down the style properties fetching with object destructuring:

```js
const character = document.getElementById("character");

function getSizeAndPositionWrong(target){
  const {left, top, width, height} = target.style;
  return {left, top, width, height};
}

function getSizeAndPositionCorrect(target){
  return  target.getBoundingClientRect();
}

console.log( getSizeAndPositionWrong(character) );
console.log( getSizeAndPositionCorrect(character) );
```

```html
<div id="character"></div>
```

### Fetching and Setting the element's style property:

Here I show instead how to use the `.style` property directly both to fetch and set the position and size of an element in real time and how to detect a collision between elements.

The very critical factor was initializing those values before the game begins and overcome the fact that size and position are encoded as a string containing the unit (`px`).

In this demo there are just two boxes approaching each other at a given speed and the game will end as soon as a collision will be detected.

These 3 functions will show the core parts:

```
this.getTargetSizeAndPosition = (target)=>{...}
this.setTargetSizeAndPosition = (target, data)=>{...}
this.checkCollision = (p1, p2)=>{...}
```

The collision detection in detail:

```
   this.checkCollision = (p1, p2)=>{
    if (p1.left + p1.width >= p2.left &&
        p1.top + p1.height >= p2.top &&
        p1.left <= p2.left + p2.width &&
        p1.top <= p2.top + p2.height)
      return true;
    return false;
  };
```

Those `p1` and `p2` objects contain the position information as number instead of string like `12px` for example. To get those numbers back and forth from the `.style` property, the value gets parsed with `parseInt` and encoded as `` `${value}px` ``.

```js
function Character(element, position = {top: 0, left: 0, width: 50, height: 50}){
  
  //------------[Public interface]------------

  //returns the size and position as integer numbers
  this.getSizeAndPosition = ()=>{
    return this.getTargetSizeAndPosition(this.target)
  };
  
  //sets the position to absolute x, y coords
  this.setPositionAbsolute = (x, y)=>{
    return this.setTargetSizeAndPosition(this.target, {left: x, top: y});
  };
  
  //sets the position by a given offsetX, offsetY
  this.setPositionByOffset = (offsetX, offsetY)=>{
    const currPos = this.getSizeAndPosition();
    const nextPos = {left: currPos.left + offsetX, top: currPos.top + offsetY}; 
    return this.setTargetSizeAndPosition(this.target, nextPos);
  };
  
  //returns true if this and obstacle collided
  this.hasCollided = (obstacle)=>{
    const p1 = this.getSizeAndPosition();
    const p2 = obstacle.getSizeAndPosition();
    
    return this.checkCollision(p1, p2);
  };
  
  //------------[Private interface]------------
  //--(showing the atomic actions in general)--

  //[HOW TO FETCH THE SIZE AND POSITION OF AN ELEMENT]
  //returns the size and position of a target element
  this.getTargetSizeAndPosition = (target)=>{
    //sets the left, top, width, height variables withe the corresponding props from .style
    const {left, top, width, height} = target.style;
    //returns those variables (parsed as numbers) wrapped in an object
    return {
      left: parseInt(left),
      top: parseInt(top),
      width: parseInt(width),
      height: parseInt(height)
    };
  };

  //[HOW TO SET THE SIZE AND POSITION OF AN ELEMENT]
  //sets the size and position of a target element
  this.setTargetSizeAndPosition = (target, data)=>{
    //converts the data content having numbers with the corresponding string containing px
    data = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => [key, `${value}px`])
    );
    //sets the .style properties as the corresponding from data (left, top, width, height)
    return Object.assign(target.style, data);
  };
  
  //[HOW TO CHECK IF TWO POSITIONS HAVE COLLIDED]
  //returns true or false if the two boxes collided
  this.checkCollision = (p1, p2)=>{
    if (p1.left + p1.width >= p2.left &&
        p1.top + p1.height >= p2.top &&
        p1.left <= p2.left + p2.width &&
        p1.top <= p2.top + p2.height)
      return true;
    return false;
  };

  //------------[Initialization]------------
  
  //it will hold the target element
  this.target = element;
    
  //initialize this object with the passed position
  this.setTargetSizeAndPosition(this.target, position);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------

const initialPositionLeft = {top: 0, left: 0, width: 50, height: 30};
const initialPositionRight = {top: 0, left: 500, width: 102, height: 120};

var loopTimer, player, enemy;

//entry point
init();
restart();

//listens for the mousemove event to update the position of Player
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event)=>{
  const target = document.querySelector('.dragging');
  if(target){
    const character = this[target.id];
    const sp = character.getSizeAndPosition();
    const offsetX = sp.width;
    const offsetY = sp.height + 20;
    character.setPositionAbsolute(event.clientX-offsetX, event.clientY-offsetY);
  }
});

//gets called be setInterval
function mainLoop(){

  player.setPositionByOffset(5, 1);
  enemy.setPositionByOffset(-5, 1);
  
  const didCollide = player.hasCollided(enemy);
  if(didCollide){
    console.log(`Did they collide? ${didCollide}`);
    stop();
    debugger;
    document.getElementById('gameover').classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}

//initializes the variables player and enemy
function init(){
  const playerTarget = document.getElementById("player");
  const enemyTarget = document.getElementById("enemy");
  player = new Character(playerTarget, initialPositionLeft);
  enemy = new Character(enemyTarget, initialPositionRight);
  
  const toggleDragging = (event)=>{ event.target.classList.toggle('dragging') };
  playerTarget.addEventListener('click', toggleDragging);
  enemyTarget.addEventListener('click', toggleDragging);
}

//restarts the game
function restart(){
  stop();
  start();
}

//resets the position of the targets
function reset(){
  player.setPositionAbsolute(initialPositionLeft.left, initialPositionLeft.top);
  enemy.setPositionAbsolute(initialPositionRight.left, initialPositionRight.top);
}

//starts the timer callback
function start(){
  document.getElementById('gameover').classList.add('hidden');
  //calls a game iteration every 10ms
  loopTimer = setInterval(mainLoop, 20);
}

//stops the timer callback
function stop(){
  clearInterval(loopTimer);
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body{
  padding: 1em 1em 1.8em 1em;
}

#game{
  position: relative;
  border: dashed .2em gray;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.box{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#player{
  border: solid 4px aqua;
  /*background: aquamarine;*/
  color: blue;
}

#enemy{
  border: solid 4px purple;
  /*background: red;*/
  color: white;
}

.commands{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}

#restart, #reset{
  padding: 1em 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: solid .2em lightgray;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#player{
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFEea.png');
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: -125px -135px;
  border: dotted 1px gray !important;
}

.dragging::after{
  content: 'click to release';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2em;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0 .7em;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

#enemy{
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ApcI.png');
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: -70px -70px;
  border: dotted 1px gray !important;
}

#gameover{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  border: solid .2em lightgray;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div id="player" class="box"></div>
  <div id="enemy" class="box"></div>
  
  <div id="gameover" class="hidden">The game is over. Try to drag the characters somewhere on the board or <b>reset</b> their position before re<b>start</b>ing the game.</div>
  
  <div class="commands">
    <button id="reset" onclick="reset();">RESET</button>
    <button id="restart" onclick="restart();">START</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just don't understand how to implement that in my code, how to call X and Y for both images?

Comment: I edited the question adding a demo detecting collisions using your very first approach despite it wasn't the best one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I am going to try this as soon as I get home from work. I’ll let you know if I have problems, but that code looks pretty solid, I doubt there will be problems. Thank you again.

Comment: of course feel free to accept the answer if it fulfilled the issue faced in the question

Comment: Yeah, I cant get it to work, I have the functions inside a function and also what is calling the collide function? how do these functions work. And I don't know what that offset is for? ```const offset1 = {left: 5, top: 1};
  const offset2 = {left: -5, top: 1};```

Comment: the code works as you can see in the demo. If you need to understand who is going to call a given function it's as easy as using find text in your editor. The main loop it's just the function `gameInfiniteLoop` called every 10ms with `setInterval`. Those offsets objects just works as arguments for the function `getTranslatedPosition`. It was needed to move by an offset every 10ms. And anyway it was beyond the question itself. I showed how to rely on the style to keep and update position state of an element in your game.

Comment: To show the concept I had to put up a whole frame with moving objects. But you have your own game and your own strategy. You just have to extrapolate the core idea I used in my demo and make it yours. That's how to deal with the style `left` and `top` to read and update the position.

Comment: I better commented that part in the code to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

So the code that was applied above by **Diego D** probably works, its just that I have been designing my game a whole different way. I mainly rely on if statements, I always try to avoid loops due to them having problems and never working correctly, they cause to many bugs. So my advice, stay away from any type of loop. They leave gaps for interfaces.

But anyway this was my approach on doing it.

```
if (enemyDetection === 0) {
    if (document.getElementById("enemy100").style.visibility === "visible" && enemy100Rotate === 0) {
        document.getElementById("enemy00").style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
        randomEnemy100Y = randomEnemy100Y - 1;
        getDetection100Y = randomEnemy100Y - 1;
        document.getElementById("enemy100").style.top = randomEnemy100Y + "vh";
        document.getElementById("enemy100").style.left = randomEnemy100X + "vw";
        }
    if (document.getElementById("enemy100").style.visibility === "visible" && enemy100Rotate === 1) {
        document.getElementById("enemy00").style.transform = "rotate(270deg)";
        randomEnemy100X = randomEnemy100X + 1;
        getDetection100X = randomEnemy100X + 1;
        document.getElementById("enemy100").style.top = randomEnemy100Y + "vh";
        document.getElementById("enemy100").style.left = randomEnemy100X + "vw";
        }
    if (document.getElementById("enemy100").style.visibility === "visible" && enemy100Rotate === 2) {
        document.getElementById("enemy00").style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
        randomEnemy100Y = randomEnemy100Y + 1;
        getDetection100Y = randomEnemy100Y + 1;
        document.getElementById("enemy100").style.top = randomEnemy100Y + "vh";
        document.getElementById("enemy100").style.left = randomEnemy100X + "vw";
    }
    if (document.getElementById("enemy100").style.visibility === "visible" && enemy100Rotate === 3) {
        document.getElementById("enemy00").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
        randomEnemy100X = randomEnemy100X - 1;
        getDetection100X = randomEnemy100X - 1;
        document.getElementById("enemy100").style.top = randomEnemy100Y + "vh";
        document.getElementById("enemy100").style.left = randomEnemy100X + "vw";
    }
}

if (getDetection100X > characterXpos - 5 && getDetection100X < characterXpos + 5 && getDetection100Y > characterYpos - 10 && getDetection100Y < characterYpos + 5) {
    enemyDetection = 1;
}
```

I added two variables, getDetectionX witch counts by 1 for each step the enemy takes on the X scale and I did the same for getDetectionY. The variables must match the Enemies attributes. (X,Y).

Then I compared the characterXpos and characterYpos with the new variables in the if statement.

Nice work around and much less code.